# Time-Driven trigger fired multiple times all the sudden after two months of working fine

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, google-docs

Hello I have created a simple Google Docs where my colleagues can input information on the roster everyday. Now, everyday, before 10 am they will have to finish putting data in. After 10 am my Time-Driven Apps Script Trigger runs and converts this google docs document into a pdf file and sends it out to specific emails.

This was working fine for the past two months. But Yesturday, All the sudden, app script sent out the same email like 5 times within 2 minutes. I have attached my code, the trigger I set on app script and my executions. Would you please take a look? Because right now I am pulling my hair and not even sure whats going on or how I can fix this.

[image: code image]

[image: executions tab]

[image: installable trigger]

[image: executions list]

Comment: The code is fine, it could have been an error of the service, if only happened once I wouldn't worry too much. Are you a G Suite user?

Comment: @Jescanellas hi there and thanks for responding. I think so. Not sure.

Comment: I see. If you are a G Suite user, in case you experience this issue again, I recommend you to head over to [G Suite Support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213?hl=en).

Comment: @Jescanellas Thanks friend. I also have another question I was just curious if possible, can you please take a look? Its in another post. And it belongs to another project. Thank you my friend. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61907507/how-to-extract-individual-array-value-from-filtered-row-in-app-script-for-google