# Edit cell value from filtered row in app script for google sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

The question is related to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61919048/10346701).

I'm filtering some rows with a specific cell value:

```
.filter(row => row[position_1] == 'value')
```

and I would like to update another cell from the selected row:

```
row[position_2] = 'new_value'
```

I have tried to include something like the previous line of code but it doesn't work.

So, if we have a code like this:

```
function selectRecords() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const dataRange = ss.getDataRange();
  const headers = 2;
  const dataValues = dataRange
    .offset(headers, 0, dataRange.getNumRows() - headers)//offsetting the headers from the whole range
    .getValues();

  dataValues
    .filter(row => row[position_1] == 'value') 
    .forEach(row => {
           //update the value of a specific cell within the row.
           //extract some cell's values: row[pos_x], row[pos_y], row[pos_z],.. to use it inside the loop
    });
}
```

How could I update a cell of each filtered row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At other method, I would like to propose to use TextFinder and RangeList for achieving your goal. The sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

Please set the variables of `position_1`, `position_2`, `searchText` and `replaceText`.

```
function selectRecords() {
  const position_1 = 1; // From your script, 1st index is 0. So, 1 is the column "B".
  const position_2 = 2; // From your script, 1st index is 0. So, 2 is the column "C".
  const searchText = "value"; // Please set the search text.
  const replaceText = "new_value"; // Please set the replace text.

  // 1. Retrieve the search range.
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const headers = 2;
  const range = ss.getRange(3, position_1 + 1, ss.getLastRow() - headers);

  // 2. Search the searchText and retrieve the range list.
  const rangeList = range.createTextFinder(searchText).matchEntireCell(true).findAll().map(r => ss.getRange(r.getRow(), position_2 + 1).getA1Notation());

  // 3. Replace the cell values using the range list.
  if (rangeList.length > 0) ss.getRangeList(rangeList).setValue(replaceText);
}
```

- The flow of this script is as follows.

  1. Retrieve the search range.
  2. Search the searchText and retrieve the range list.
  3. Replace the cell values using the range list.
- In this case, only cell values for replacing are replaces. So, even when the cells except for the replaced cells have the formulas, this script can be used.

#### References:

- [createTextFinder(findText)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#createtextfinderfindtext)
- [Class TextFinder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder)
- [getRangeList(a1Notations)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangelista1notations)
- [Class RangeList](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range-list)

Comment: Very clear and well explained answer. Inside my forEach I need to extract some cell's values (because I use it to build an update for BigQuery). For example: row[x], row[y], row[z]. Is there any way to extract these cell's values using your code? Because right now I would need to keep both functions and I would like to improve the performance doing all at once.

Comment: @IoT user Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question, I would like to support you. But I have to apologize for my poor English skill. From `For example: row[x], row[y], row[z]. Is there any way to extract these cell's values using your code?`, I cannot understand about your new question. In order to correctly understand about your new question, can I ask you about the detail of your new question? Can you provide the sample input and output values you expect? By this, I would like to try to understand your new question.

Answer (score 2):

### You have to use setValues instead

I'd use .map() function with a conditional inside the arrow function instead due to the nature of Spreadsheet with regards to Apps Script which requires a two-dimensional array of values in order to set values. Here's my approach:

```
function selectRecords() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const dataRange = ss.getDataRange();
  const headers = 2;
  const dataValues = dataRange
    .offset(headers, 0, dataRange.getNumRows() - headers)//offsetting the headers from the whole range
    .getValues();

  dataValues = dataValues.map(row => {
                 if(row[position_1] !== 'value') return row
                 
                 // Update the value and return row
                 row[position_2] = 'new_value'
                 return row
               });

  dataRange
    .offset(headers, 0, dataRange.getNumRows() - headers)
    .setValues(dataValues);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say we want to find all rows that contain "a1" in first cell and change second cell of these rows to "zzz":

```js
var dataValues = [
    ["a1", "b1", "c1"],
    ["a2", "b2", "c2"],
    ["a3", "b3", "c3"],
    ["a1", "b1", "c1"],
    ["a2", "b2", "c2"],
    ["a3", "b3", "c3"]
];

var value      = "a1";
var position_1 = 0;
var new_value  = "zzz";
var position_2 = 1;

var filtered_dataValues = dataValues.filter(row => {
    if (row[position_1] == value) { row[position_2] = new_value; return row; }
    else { return false; }
});

console.log(filtered_dataValues); // [ [ 'a1', 'zzz', 'c1' ], [ 'a1', 'zzz', 'c1' ] ]
```